# I killed all the badgers, where do I get more?

Tags: towns

I've killed all the badgers on the map, and I do not have a badger farm.

Is there a way to get more badgers so I can start a badger farm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. To make a badger farm you'll have to start over. Hopefully future versions of Towns will introduce another way for them to respawn.